# Calculating Average over different intervals

Tags: mysql, join, average

In mysql, I am calculating averages of the same metric over different intervals (3 Day, 7 Day, 30 Day, 60 Day, etc...), and I need the results to be in a single line per `id`.

Currently, I am using a Join per each interval. Given that I have to compute this for many different stores, and over several different intervals, is there a cleaner and/or more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Below is the code I am currently using.

Thanks in advance for the help

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.DailySales_3DayAvg, T2.DailySales_7DayAvg
FROM(
    SELECT id, avg(DailySales) as 'DailySales_3DayAvg'
    FROM `SalesTable`
    WHERE `Store`=2 
      AND `Date` >= DATE_SUB('2012-07-28', INTERVAL 3 DAY)
      AND `Date` < '2012-07-28' 
) AS T1

JOIN(
    SELECT id, avg(DailySales) as 'DailySales_7DayAvg'
    FROM `SalesTable`
    WHERE `Store`=2 
      AND `Date` >= DATE_SUB('2012-07-28', INTERVAL 7 DAY)
      AND `Date` < '2012-07-28' 
) AS T2

ON T1.ArtistId = T2.ArtistId
```

Where the results are:

```
  id   DailySales_3DayAvg   DailySales_7DayAvg
3752              1234.56              1114.78
...
```

Comment: No, I don't think there is...unless you'd like to generate the averages in the receiving program AFTER you got the data from mySQL...though subqueries would at least remove the 'JOINS'. (But aren't any prettier)

Comment: What do you mean by "average"?  What do you mean by "over an interval"?  Currently, you're taking the mean `DailySales` of all records in the SalesTable (for the given store) that fall within the respective date range.  However, this is not the "average daily sales" over the period: consider what happens where a store has multiple (or no) records for a particular day within the interval: perhaps instead you want to take the sum of all sales and divide by the number of days?  Define the problem more explicitly, then we can help suggest possible answers.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium, thanks for the reply.  The data is historical, and is then going into R.  I can easily calculate it in R, but it is much faster doing it in sql. Looks like I'm sticking with the code as it is. thank you.

Comment: @eggyal, I appreciate your feedback, but I this is all very well understood.   Furthermore, the average is computed as expected (ie, if there are missing values, say only 3 records in 7 days, then the mean is computed as `sum(vals) / 3`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query like this -

```
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(IF(date >= '2012-07-28' - INTERVAL 3 DAY, DailySales, 0)) / 
    COUNT(IF(date >= '2012-07-28' - INTERVAL 3 DAY, 1, NULL)) 'DailySales_3DayAvg',

  SUM(IF(date >= '2012-07-28' - INTERVAL 7 DAY, DailySales, 0)) / 
    COUNT(IF(date >= '2012-07-28' - INTERVAL 7 DAY, 1, NULL)) 'DailySales_7DayAvg'
FROM
  SalesTable
WHERE
  Store = 2 AND Date < '2012-07-28'
GROUP BY
  id
```

Comment: I would add that you can also group by store, if that is important.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in any other way if you want to pull real-time data. However, if you can afford displaying slightly outdated data, you could pre-calculate these average (like once or twice a day) for each item.

You may want to look into the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html), which allows you to keep everything inside MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll take a look at the scheduler. Cheers